# Why minor GC time increase when I increase new age memory

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I use 2G new age memory before, I saw the minor gc happens every 10 seconds and takes 0.1-0.15 second each time, I want to reduce minor gc frequency so I set new age memory to 3G. After that minor gc happens every 15 seconds, but however it takes about 0.3 second to complete. Why minor GC time increase when I increase new age memory? I noticed that after I increase memory, active object after GC increase from 55M to 80M, what is the reason?

Comment: *"minor gc happens every 10 seconds and takes 0.1-0.15 second each"* - that's 1 to 1.5% of wall time spent in GC. Why do you want fewer pauses than that? Shouldn't you aim for individual lower pause times instead if request latency is a concern?

Comment: @the8472, my server CPU load is very high, but have many memory resource not used. I want to reduce GC to lower CPU load, seems not a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is, there are more live objects in the larger memory region. GC time primarily scales with the number (and overall size) of live objects that have to be copied to the survivor region.

You can profit from a larger young generation region only if you create many objects that all live at the same time and don't fully fit into YG. That forces them to be tenured into the Old Generation.

Otherwise the total GC time stays the same and you just choose how to split it into individual stop-the-world events: longer and less frequent or shorter and more frequent.

Comment: My application logic is very simple, it just receive request, convert the received data, and send to another server. So I think live objects is depends on how many requests is processing, as after request finished, all objects are released. If the requests per seconds is the same, why live objects increase when memory region increase?

Comment: That's hardly something anyone except you can find out. Maybe there's less tenuring, as I described?

Comment: I print tenuring details in gc log, no matter before or after I change YG memory, there is almost nothing tenured into OG. Actually, almost all objects are collected in age 0 or age 1. The difference is with 2G YG, age 1 objects is about 55M, and with 3G YG, age 1 objects is about 80M.

Comment: @Xilang if live objects is increasing it means more objects are being retaining than you think. Medium lived objects are really expensive so identified and reducing them can make a big difference.  Try taking a jmap -history before minor gc. Increase the Eden to say 24 GB if you need to slow it down enough.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to increase the time between young collections, you want to increase the Eden size.  When you change the young generation size you are likely to be also changing two things, the size of the survivor spaces and the tenuring threshold. The tenuring theshold determine how many times objects are copied back and forth between survivor spaces before being promoted to the tenured space. The default tenuring threshold is 4 but certain parameters such as `-Xmn` change the tenuring threshold to 15, unless you also specify it.

You can increase the Eden space by setting the `-XX:SurvivorRatio=8` form example and limit the tenuring theshold to say `-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=4` The downside of limiting the tenuring threshold is that more object will be promoted to tenuring space, which places pressure on your Full GC.

Before attempting to tenure your GC, I always recommend you do a memory profile looking at allocation e.g. with Flight Recorder. Often I find you can reduce your garbage rate by 2-4x and this will make tuning your application much easier.

Comment: In GC log, i saw the tenuring threshold is 6, in both 2G and 3G case. There is almost nothing tenured into OG. Actually, almost all objects are collected in age 0 or age 1. The difference is with 2G YG, age 1 objects is about 55M, and with 3G YG, age 1 objects is about 80M.